# Can't run Azure data factory from Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

This is my c# Azure Function script:

```
#r "System.Runtime"
#r "System.Threading.Tasks"
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Rest;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    /*...All variable definations...*/


var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(activeDirectoryEndpoint + activeDirectoryTenantld);    
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientld, clientSecret);    
AuthenticationResult result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(windowsManagementUri, credential).Result; 
ServiceClientCredentials cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
var client = new DataFactoryManagementClient(cred) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

Dictionary<string, object> arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "bufferdays", 10 },
                {"TimeToCopy", 20 }
            };    
CreateRunResponse runResponse = client.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, dataFactoryName, pipelineName,arguments).Result.Body;

}
```

This throws error ***run.csx(56,130): error CS1503: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'string'***
. But the same thing works fine in Visual Studio. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
I was using {
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {

        "Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory": "0.8.0",
```

in project.json so automatically it was downloading version 1.0.0. I had to force it to download version 0.8.0 by specifying `"Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactory": "0.8.0-preview",` explicitly.